How to send asynchronous json using Perl to an PHP url?
I am trying to send some data in json format with POST to a specific url test.php. The request should be asynchronous , I need to get the http response code if the data is sent or not (I don't wont to wait until the request is done processed on test.php).
I have built a perl function to send the data
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw(encode_json);
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;


=pod
Function send asynchronus data , get response code 
=cut
sub sendOutboundPostRequestAsync {
    my ($url, $data, $token) = @_;

    # Create a condition variable to wait for the asynchronous request
    my $request_done = AnyEvent->condvar;

    # Convert the data hash to JSON
    my $json_data = encode_json($data);
    print "JSON data being sent: $json_data\n";  # For debugging

    # Make the HTTP POST request asynchronously
    http_post $url,
        headers => {
            'Authorization' => $token,
            'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
        },
        body => $json_data,
        sub {
            my ($body, $headers) = @_;
            my $status_code = $headers->{Status} // 500;  # Default to 500 if no status
            
            # Print the response for debugging
            print "Response Body: $body\n";
            print "Request completed with status code: $status_code\n";

            # Send the status code back through the condition variable
            $request_done->send($status_code);
        };

    return $request_done;  # Return the condition variable for further processing
}


#####
my $url = 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx/test.php';
my $token = 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGci'; 

# Example data to send
my %data = (
    uniqueid => '1727331196.gesti',
    start_time => '2024-09-26 08:13:17',
);

# Call the function
my $response_code_condvar = sendOutboundPostRequestAsync($url, \%data, $token);
my $response_code         = $response_code_condvar->recv;  # Wait for the request to complete

print "Final Response Code: $response_code\n";


The php code (shortened for testing purpose) to get the data
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
    
// Retrieve the raw POST data
$postData = file_get_contents('php://input');

// Log all headers for debugging
$headers = getallheaders();
file_put_contents('postData.txt', "Received Headers:\n" . print_r($headers, true) . "\n", FILE_APPEND);

// Specify the file path
$file_path = 'postData.txt';

// Open the file for writing (append mode)
$file = fopen($file_path, 'a'); // Use 'w' to overwrite the file
  
// Write the POST data to the file
fwrite($file, "Received POST data:\n" . $postData . "\n\n");
    
// Close the file
fclose($file);  

// Decode the JSON data
$data = json_decode($postData, true);

// Check if data decoding was successful
if ($data === null) {
    // Handle error: Invalid JSON
    http_response_code(400);
    echo 'Invalid JSON';
    exit;
}

// Extract the action from the decoded data
$action = $data['action'] ?? null;

// Check if the action is set
if ($action === null) {
    // Handle error: Missing action
    http_response_code(400);
    echo 'Missing action';
    exit;
}   
?>


Issue
After executing the Perl script I get
ast1:~ # perl test.agi
JSON data being sent: {"start_time":"2024-09-26 08:13:17","uniqueid":"1727331196.gesti"}
Response Body: Invalid JSON
Request completed with status code: 400
Final Response Code: 400

The data seems correct and it should be sent without issue, but on the PHP side on the text log I get
Received POST data:
headers


Desired output
Received POST data:
{
    "start_time": "2024-09-26 08:13:17",
    "uniqueid": "1727331196.gesti"
}

What could be the issue of an empty result of data?

Just to be certain, are you sure there's no chance of a redirect happening, for instance with a WWW or HTTPS, because the POST body would be lost then.

@ChrisHaas no, there is no redirect . IMO I think I am messing something up on the perl part , I can not figured out

You're doing
http_post $url, headers => {...}, body => $json_data, sub {... }

but that doesn't match the signature in the documentation, which says
http_post $url, $body, key => value..., $cb->($data, $headers)

That is, the body is the second argument, and isn't passed as a key-value pair. Since you got the order wrong, it's interpreting headers as the body, and mixing up everything else.
So if you want to use http_post (rather than http_request) with your example, it would be
http_post $url, $json_data, headers => { ... }, sub { ... }


@ErgestBasha np. For what it's worth, you should feel free to continue using http_request, since it's "less weird". Other than the difference in calling convention, they work exactly the same.

Since hobbs response answered my question I will post the full code for future readers to benefit from .
I ended up with the following code.
When the request is successfully but it takes some time to process I have added a timer to kill the process.
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON qw(encode_json);
use AnyEvent;
use AnyEvent::HTTP;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";

# Function to send a POST request asynchronously
# It expects the $data array , $token as parameter and $callToSend which is the url where the post should be sent
sub sendOutboundPostRequestAsync {
    my ($data, $token, $callToSend) = @_;

    my $url = '';

    # Set the URL based on the call type
    if ($callToSend eq "OutboundCall") {
            $url = 'https://outboundCalls';
    }
    elsif ($callToSend eq "InboundCall") {
            $url = 'https://inboundCalls';
    }
    elsif ($callToSend eq "TechnicCall") {
            $url = 'https://technicCalls'; 
    }
    elsif ($callToSend eq "TechnicToClientCall") {
            $url = 'https://technicToClientCalls';  
    } else {
        warn "Invalid call type: $callToSend\n";
        return 400;  # Return immediately with 400 status code for invalid request
    }

    # Convert the data hash to JSON
    my $json_data = encode_json($data);
    #print "JSON data being sent: $json_data\n";  # For debugging

    # Fork the process
    my $pid = fork();

    if (!defined $pid) {
        die "Failed to fork: $!";
    }

    if ($pid == 0) {
        # Child process: Make the HTTP POST request asynchronously
        http_post $url,
            $json_data,
            headers => {
                'Authorization' => $token,
                'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
            },
            sub {
                my ($body, $headers) = @_;
                my $status_code = $headers->{Status} // 500;  # Default to 500 if no status

                # Print the response for debugging
                #print "Request completed in child process with status code: $status_code\n";
                exit $status_code;  # Exit with the HTTP status code as the exit code
            };

        AnyEvent->condvar->recv;  # This waits for the async request to finish
        exit 1;  # In case of failure to ensure child exits if we reach here
    }

    # Parent process: Wait for a maximum of 0.3 seconds for the child process to complete
    my $timeout = 0.2;
    my $start_time = time;

    while (1) {
        my $pid_res = waitpid($pid, WNOHANG);

        if ($pid_res == -1) {
            # Child process already finished
            #print "Child process has already exited\n";
            return 500;  # Return some error code if the child fails
        } elsif ($pid_res == 0) {
            # Child process is still running
            if (time - $start_time > $timeout) {
                #print "Timeout reached. Returning 202 status.\n";
                kill 'TERM', $pid;  # Kill the child process after timeout
                return 202;  # Return 202 (Accepted)
            }
            # Sleep briefly to prevent busy waiting
            sleep 0.1;
        } else {
            # Child has exited, collect its exit status
            my $exit_status = $? >> 8;  # Get the actual exit code
            #print "Child process exited with status: $exit_status\n";
            return $exit_status;  # Return the actual status code from the child process
        }
    }
}

